# Ajax call not working on datatables pages,except first page

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i am using datatables.And on the table there is button on each row.

When I click on the trash button,ajax works only for the first 10 row.
But when I move on to next pages it does not work anymore.

Here is my table code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>

      <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="success">Id</th>
        <th class="success">Image</th>
        <th class="success">Title</th>
        <th class="success">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM movie");
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
            echo'
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$result[0].'</td>
                        <td><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:50px;" src="'.$result[5].'"></td>
                        <td>'.$result[1].'</td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                          <label id="remID" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                          <span class="text-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                          </label>
                          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                          <span class="text-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                          </label>
                        </div> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            ';
            echo'
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#remID").click(function(){
    $.post("remMovie.php",
    {
      id:"'.$result[0].'"
    },
    function(data,status){
    alert(status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my PHP part of ajax action:

```
<?php
include('adminchk.php');
include('config.php');
$movieID = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE from movie where id='$movieID'");
if ($query){
    echo"movie deleted";
}
else {
    echo"ERROR!";
}
?>
```

I dont know why this is happening.I want the trash button to work for every row of datatable.

Answer (score 4):

To execute any Code after the Data Table has been paginated (basically redrawn), you need to add `fnDrawCallback` function inside `.dataTabale()` method. All codes written inside the Callback function will work after the table has been redrawn. Here is an example...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {

            // Write any code (also ajax code that you want to execute)
            // that you want to be executed after 
            // the table has been redrawn             

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like `fnDrawCallback` event.

**Here is the doc** : http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback

When the datable change, you bind the buttons with the function you want.

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
  } );
} );
```