# datatables jquery click event not working after pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using http://datatables.net/

```
<button class='btn btn-success activeAccount'>Activate Account</button>
```

I trigger ajax call on onclick event, below is ajax call code:

```
$(".activeAccount").click(function() {
  var intCounselorId = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[class="counselorId"]').attr("value");
  var intOwnerId = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[class="userID"]').attr("value");
  var strAction = 'activateAccount';
  performAction(intCounselorId, intOwnerId, strAction);
});

function performAction(intCounselorId, intOwnerId, strAction) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/admin/counselormanagement/expertmanagementgridaction',
      data: 'intCounselorId='+intCounselorId+'&intOwnerId='+intOwnerId+'&strAction='+strAction,
      type: "POST",
      async:false,
      success: function(intFlag) {
        if(intFlag == 1){
          location.reload();
        }
      }
  });
}
```

I'm trying to run an onclick event which works normally on page one, but as soon as I go to page 2 (or any other) it stops working.

I'm using jquery-1.10.2.min.js and 1.9.4 version of datatable

Comment: Is the `.activeAccount` button inside the content of the table? Also, note that it's really bad practice to use `async: false`, and the `location.reload()` in the success handler completely negates the entire point of making an AJAX request in the first place.

Comment: yes, it is under content of the table

Comment: In that case you need to use a delegated event handler, as per @squaleLis's answer. You really should get rid of `async: false` and the `location.reload()` though.

Comment: I have given an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575996/ajax-call-not-working-on-datatables-pages-except-first-page You may see this.

Comment: The solution suggested by @Md.HarunOrRashid is really helpful

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Because the event is attached only to existing elements.

You should change it to:

```
$("#tableId").on("click", ".activeAccount", function(){
   // your code goes here
});
```

Read more in the documentation of [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @sarower-jahan Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, Its really helpful answer.

Comment: In my case, before the click event was 
"$(".each_player").click(function(){ // my code goes here });"

After modifying,

"$("#playerGroupUI").on("click", ".each_player", function(){ // my code goes here });"

Comment: this fired the event multiple times instead of once!? 10 delete icons on the page and upon clicking one the delete confirm was fired twice

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).on("click",".activeAccount",function(e){
 // your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Every time my AJAX function(modalContentAjaxRefresh) update the table the paging stop. SO I just had to change my code from :

From :

> $('.modal-toggle').off('click', modalContentAjaxRefresh).on('click',
>   modalContentAjaxRefresh);

to:

> $('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').on("click", ".modal-toggle",
>   modalContentAjaxRefresh);

My button inside datatable is :

> < a title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info **modal-toggle**"
>   data-style="zoom-in"
>   href="/setting/account/{{account_turn.uuid}}/update"
>   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAccount" wecare-method="GET">

Answer (score 2):

As @squaleLis said, the event is attached to only existing elements.

So, in my case I defined onclick event for the button and called it.

```
  <button class='btn btn-success activeAccount' onclick="YourMethod();">Activate Account</button>

  function YourMethod() {
     ....same code..
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#product-list").on("click",".btn-delete-product",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodId     =   $(this).attr("product-id"); 
    .... code to delete the record from the db...
  });
```

*product-list* is the table where data gets loaded and has paging enabled.

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks a good and easy solution is to use [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option

Answer (score -1):

The main important thing is to reassign the elements when click the pagination.

```
//function to assign event
var assign_actions = function(){
  //Some code  
}
  //when the page is ready
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    assign_actions();
    //Code to assign event when paginate
     $('.paginate_button').on('click', function(){
       assign_actions();
     });
   });
```