# jQuery Datatable - I keep getting undefined when i call a row data from a json datatable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables, metronic

Im currently developing a project at my job, im using Laravel as my framework and im using KeenThemes as my frontend. I believe they have their variation of the Datatables library and maybe that's why im having this issue. Since i can't find a well documented example of the metronic Datatable library im using the original Datatable documentation to work on this project. Ok, so on to the problem. This is my blade component for the datatable.

```
<div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile  m-portlet--rounded">
<div class="m-portlet__head">
    <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
            {{$title}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-portlet__head-tools">
        {{$buttons}}
        <ul class="m-portlet__nav">
            <li class="m-portlet__nav-item">
                <div class="m-dropdown m-dropdown--inline m-dropdown--arrow m-dropdown--align-right m-dropdown--align-push" m-dropdown-toggle="hover"
                    aria-expanded="true">
                    <a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn btn-lg btn-secondary  m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill  m-dropdown__toggle">
                                <i class="la la-ellipsis-h m--font-brand"></i>
                            </a>
                    <div class="m-dropdown__wrapper">
                        <span class="m-dropdown__arrow m-dropdown__arrow--right m-dropdown__arrow--adjust"></span>
                        <div class="m-dropdown__inner">
                            <div class="m-dropdown__body">
                                <div class="m-dropdown__content">
                                    <ul class="m-nav">
                                        <li class="m-nav__section m-nav__section--first">
                                            <span class="m-nav__section-text">Acciones</span>
                                        </li>
                                        {{$actions}}
                                        <li class="m-nav__separator m-nav__separator--fit m--hide">
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="m-nav__item m--hide">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--wide btn-sm">Submit</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="m-portlet__body">

    {{-- begin - search input --}}

    <div class="m-form m-form--label-align-right m--margin-top-20 m--margin-bottom-30">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-xl-8 order-2 order-xl-1">
                <div class="form-group m-form__group row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="m-form__group m-form__group--inline">
                            <div class="m-form__label">
                                <label>Status:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-form__control">
                                <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select" id="m_form_estado">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option value="1">En servicio</option>
                                        <option value="6">En Busqueda</option>
                                        <option value="5">En Saneamiento</option>
                                        <option value="3">En Obra</option>
                                        <option value="2">En Instalación</option>
                                        <option value="4">Listo Para Ejecutar</option>
                                        <option value="12">Sin Estado</option>
                                        <option value="14">Caido</option>
                                        <option value="15">Retirado</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="m-form__group m-form__group--inline">
                            <div class="m-form__label">
                                <label class="m-label m-label--single">Type:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-form__control">
                                <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select" id="m_form_type">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option value="1">Online</option>
                                        <option value="2">Retail</option>
                                        <option value="3">Direct</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="m-input-icon m-input-icon--left">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Search..." id="generalSearch">
                            <span class="m-input-icon__icon m-input-icon__icon--left">
                                    <span><i class="la la-search"></i></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- end - search input --}}


    <!--begin: Datatable -->
    <div class="m_datatable" id="m_datatable"></div>

    <!--end: Datatable -->

</div>
```

Now, this is some of the javascript im using to render and fill the table with data. The part im gonna paste is where i define the fuction to search data and also the definition of the column i wanna get from the row.

```
{
   field: "IdEstacion",
   title: "#",
   width: 40,
   sortable: !0,
   selector: !1,
   textAlign: "center",
   responsive: {
      hidden: 'lg'
   },
   template: '{{IdEstacion}}',
   query: {},
   sort: {
      sort: "asc",
      field: "IdEstacion"
   }
   {...}
   $("#m_datatable").on("click", "tr", function () {
      var tr=$(this).parents("tr")[0];
      var row=t.row(row).data();
      console.log(row));
      alert(row);
   })
```

I've checked the console and also checked the values in the debug and row is returning an object, however, it is returning the whole datatable not just the row i clicked on. And when I try to reference a value from the row variable i keep getting undefined on the console and on the alert. Am i missing something? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: adding my json structure

[JSON value #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0vLp.png)

Comment: `var row=t.row(row).data();` this looks super weird to me. What are variable `t` and `row`? Strange.

Comment: sorry, t is my datatable. that's the name i gave it. and row is taken from an example i saw at the datatable api forums.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `var row=t.row(tr).data()` ?

Comment: @lofihelsinki yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#YourTable tbody').on( 'click', 'a', function () {
              var data = '';
              data = YourTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
              //to do this your table need to be declared like this
             //yourTable= $('#YourTable').DataTable();
              console.log(data);
              var carId= data['id'];
              console.log(carId);
})
```

Comment: but, in `data = YourTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();`, is `YourTable` a reference to `exampleTable` or `'#YourTable'` in `exampleTable = $('#YourTable').DataTable();`?

Comment: @HéctorTorres-Calderón it means your table id

Comment: @HéctorTorres-Calderón declare the table like this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688932/jq-event-didnt-active-on-the-extract-row-sort-by-datatable-js/54713331#54713331

Answer (score 0):

The idea is right, but there seem to be a few typos in your example.

`var tr=$(this).parents("tr")[0]` is not needed, change `row` to `this` in `var row=t.row(row).data();`

There's a syntax problem in `console.log(row));`

Also, `t` needs to be defined.

```
var t = $("#m_datatable").DataTable();

t.on("click", "tr", function () {
      var row = t.row(this).data();
      console.log(row);
      alert(row);
})
```