# get id from datatable and show his results into a modal ASP SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a datatable in an aspx page connected to an mssql database, I added a column with a button to open the modal in which I would like to show the results for the selected record. How do I pass the record id and run a sql query to show the fields that interest me?

```
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready(function() {
$('#dt1').DataTable({

    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "selectbasic.aspx",
        dataSrc : ''
    },
    "columns" : [
     {
     "data": "ID",


     },
     {
         "data" : "Name"
     },
     {
        "data" : "Email"
    },
      {
        "data" : "Address"
    }, {
        "data" : "UserType",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
        if(type === 'display'){

        if(data=="0"){
        data="NO";
        }else
        {
        data="SI";
        }

            data = data;
        }
        return data;
     }
    },
    {  data : 'edit',
      render : function(data, type, row) {
          return '<center><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaldetails"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></center>'

      }
    },
  ]


});
</script>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modaldetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 100;">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


          "show results here where ID=...."



            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In practice I would like to do what with php & mysql is done using $ _GET ['ID'] and mysql_fetch_assoc (), but in asp & mssql. Thank you

Comment: Hi do you want to use another datatable inside the modal or you just want to query some info ?

Comment: Hi, i want to run a query to show the details of the selected record (all the various fields that are not mentioned in the datatable..), in this case within the modal but can also be in a popup or in another page. The important thing is to be able to extract the data of the selected record.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
 $('#YourTable tbody').on( 'click', 'a', function () {
              var data = '';
              data = YourTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
              //to do this your table need to be declared like this
             //yourTable= $('#YourTable').DataTable();
              console.log(data);
              var carId= data['id'];
              console.log(carId);
})
```

if you have any issue check this post where i answered something similar [JQ event didnt active on the extract row sort by datatable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688932/jq-event-didnt-active-on-the-extract-row-sort-by-datatable-js/54713331#54713331)