# html Dynamic table edit button on click event does not load the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

my end objective is to edit the json data and post back to the server if there is any update on the row

I am using the following code to get the json data to the table and add an edit button at the end column dynamically.

```
$.getJSON("echo_int_ip.php", function get_mem_update(json) {
                my_json = json;
                var tr;
                var n=5;

                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    var mem_date = "<td style=\"min-width:90px\"><label id='mem_date'>" + my_json[i].id + "</label></td>";
                    tr.append(mem_date);
                    var mem_name = "<td class=\"contact_name\" style=\"min-width:150px\"><label id='mem_name'>" + my_json[i].fi_name + "</label></td>";
                    tr.append(mem_name);
                    var mem_reason = "<td><label id='mem_reason'>" + my_json[i].agent_ + "</label></td>";
                    tr.append(mem_reason);
                    var mem_comment = "<td style=\"max-width:150px\"><label id='mem_comment'>" + my_json[i].date + "</label></td>";
                    tr.append(mem_comment);
                    var mem_butn = "<td><input type=\"button\" id=\"btnedt\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
                    tr.append(mem_butn);
                    $('#table_member').append(tr);

                }
            });
```

according to the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858738/datatables-jquery-click-event-not-working-after-pagination), i have used the the following script to create an onclick event and get row data.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnedt', function() {
         //   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.contact_name').text());
$("#newModal").modal("show");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is a sample modal i am currently trying to load but it does not work. i have spent hours trying figure out a way, but ended up asking from you experts. Thank you in advance

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: provide code of "#newModal" also

Comment: @tuhin47 added, sorry it was missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't have many id's with the same value in a one html page. Cause it will result an error in the future while your doing a lot of code to it. Please change your btnedt to a class not an id. then change your script like this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on('click', '.btnedt', function() {
              //   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.contact_name').text());
              $("#newModal").modal("show");
         });
    });
</script>
```

if modal is already the issue. Then here some reason's why its not appearing

1. **Remove the fade class in your modal.**
2. **The versions of your Javascript and Bootstrap does not match.**
3. **You forgot to include bootstrap.js library in the document**

please check this out [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672304/bootstrap-mymodal-modalshow-is-not-working)

Comment: Hi, i tried, yet modal does not show, however i checked with setting out an alert, it works. therefore, its just the modal that does not pops

Comment: are you sure the modal actually works inside  $(document).on('click', '.btnedt', function() {. I checked everything you mentioned but no. I looked into many answers but nothing was found in the aforementioned function.

Comment: Definitely it will work. That's impossible. If that's the case then can you show it in jsfiddle or show all what you have.

Comment: Hey, code actually works, i have missed a div in the previous modal.

Answer (score 0):

## Use class instead of multiple IDs

> Share your modal code

```
var mem_butn = "<td><input type=\"button\" class=\"btnedt\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('body').on('click', '.btnedt', function() {
              $("#newModal").modal("show");
         });
    });
</script>
```